# An integration problem: $\int_{p}^{1}\Phi^{-1}(x)dx$

Tags: integration, statistics, normal-distribution

X is an r.v following standard normal distribution, I would like to show $\int_{p}^{1}\Phi^{-1}(x)dx=f_{X}[\Phi^{-1}(p)]$. 
Furthermore, if X follows LogN($\mu$, $\sigma^{2}$), how to proof $\int_{p}^{1}e^{\sigma*\Phi^{-1}(x)+\mu}dx=e^{\mu+\sigma^{2}/2}*\Phi[\sigma-\Phi^{-1}(p)]$?
Hope someone can help me..I am ganna go insane..